# Different dimensions matrices multiplication in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I need to multiply the following matrices that has different dimensions:

```
a= [[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]]

b= [[[ 0.50709072  0.50709072  0.50709072  0.50709072  0.50709072
    0.50709072]
  [ 0.50156421  0.50156421  0.50156421  0.50156421  0.50156421
    0.50156421]
  [ 0.4934983   0.4934983   0.4934983   0.4934983   0.4934983
    0.4934983 ]
  [ 0.49774671  0.49774671  0.49774671  0.49774671  0.49774671
    0.49774671]]

 [[-0.50156421 -0.50156421 -0.50156421 -0.50156421 -0.50156421
   -0.50156421]
  [ 0.83307796  0.83307796  0.83307796  0.83307796  0.83307796
    0.83307796]
  [-0.16423768 -0.16423768 -0.16423768 -0.16423768 -0.16423768
   -0.16423768]
  [-0.16565156 -0.16565156 -0.16565156 -0.16565156 -0.16565156
   -0.16565156]]

 [[-0.4934983  -0.4934983  -0.4934983  -0.4934983  -0.4934983
   -0.4934983 ]
  [-0.16423768 -0.16423768 -0.16423768 -0.16423768 -0.16423768
   -0.16423768]
  [ 0.83840351  0.83840351  0.83840351  0.83840351  0.83840351
    0.83840351]
  [-0.16298763 -0.16298763 -0.16298763 -0.16298763 -0.16298763
   -0.16298763]]

 [[-0.49774671 -0.49774671 -0.49774671 -0.49774671 -0.49774671
   -0.49774671]
  [-0.16565156 -0.16565156 -0.16565156 -0.16565156 -0.16565156
   -0.16565156]
  [-0.16298763 -0.16298763 -0.16298763 -0.16298763 -0.16298763
   -0.16298763]
  [ 0.83560924  0.83560924  0.83560924  0.83560924  0.83560924
    0.83560924]]]

c= [[4.55965106 4.55965106 4.55965106 4.55965106 4.55965106 4.55965106]]
```

The shapes of the matrices are

u_1.shape, s_1.shape, vh_1.shape
((4, 4, 6), (1, 6), (1, 1, 6))

I got the error massage:

matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 6)

How can i multiply such matrices ?

Comment: Could you please add the intended output? Or exactly which matrix multiplication (mathematically) you want?

Comment: Which kind of multiplication?  The error message is produced by `@`, `np.matmul`.  That has very specific rules for how 3d arrays are used together.  Have you read that?  For element-wise multiplication (using `*`) those arrays should work.  But for `@` you'll have to elaborate on what you expect to happen.